# Can the authors grant the permission to reuse figures copyrighted by the publisher?

Tags: copyright

I'm preparing a article for possible publication on the journal “Progress in Aerospace Sciences” (published by Elsevier).

I plan to reuse some figures cited from articles published and copyrighted by AIAA.

I tried the Copyright Clearance Center, but to be honest, I may not accept the price.

Thus, I'm trying to contact directly with the authors
(the lead author if no correspondence author is noted).

Can the authors grant me the permission?

Comment: Think of it this way: the authors signed over copyright to the publisher when they sent the paper for publication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If the copyright in the articles lies with AIAA, then it is they who must license it, or parts of it.

You may be able to recreate a similar diagram, acknowledging the original one.

(I am not a lawyer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use figures under [fair reuse](https://guides.library.yale.edu/copyright-guidance/using-copyrightedworks#s-lib-ctab-10462736-1), there is **no need to ask**.

Comment: Note that fair use exemptions aren't unlimited, or universal. Depending on circumstances there may be need to ask.

Comment: @origimbo Yes, you're right